# C++: What does the build option "-j" mean?

Tags: c++, build, cmake, ros, catkin

I have a project, which consists of C++ code and uses CMake as build system and above that uses the Catkin tool `catkin_make` to build the project. The thing is, it does or does not build depending on weather I use the build option `-j` as in `catkin_make -j4`. (working only for `-j1`) I googled/stackoverflowed already, but could not find out the meaning of this option.

I believe that `-j` is often also used in other C++/CMake projects not using Catkin, so maybe someone can give me an expaination.

Thanks!

Comment: `-j4` will consume more memory compared to `-j1`. Are you running out of memory with `-j4`?

Comment: Ok, great! I don't think it's catkin dependent anyway. Just wanted to state that as additional info. Thanks also for the gihub link. And no I don't think it is a memory issue. I got `Failed to build target 'all'` and `make -j2 -l2 failed`. Pretty cryptic because the makefiles get generated by catkin/CMake automatically.

Comment: CMake-generated makefiles support `VERBOSE=1` for debugging, so try that in addition to `-j4`.

Comment: @MSalters: Thanks! That was great advice. Enabled me to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At their [github repository](https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/kinetic-devel/bin/catkin_make) they say that the `-j` parameter is passed directly to the `make` command.

> The `-j` (`--jobs`) and `-l` (`--load-average`) arguments for make are also extracted and passed to make directly

So `-jN` indicates the number of jobs run in parallel.